# Internal Server Error trying to upload a new version of native Google docs file

Tags: google-drive-api

I am getting 500 Internal Error - when I try to upload a new version of a 'Google Drive Document/Presentation' { The new version is a specific doc/ppt file that I have to upload }.

I do not get the error when I try it for the 'Spreadsheet'.

Is it not possible

I really appreciate your promptness.

P.S. This is the endpoint I am sending the request to - https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v2/files/{fileId}?uploadType=multipart

Sort of related to - [change Google Drive mimeType on update file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15946470/change-google-drive-mimetype-on-update-file)

But, I don't get a bad response. I get a 500 Internal Server error - that makes me wonder if there's something wrong at the drive end ?

If I had to accomplish this, what options do I have ?

Comment: first issue is to isolate whether this is a transient Drive problem (happens a lot) or a problem with your upload request. So (1) does it fail every time, out of say 10 attempts, (2) can you paste the http request and response so we can check the specifics

Comment: It fails deterministically for word/presentation.
However, for spreadsheet I can successfully upload the 'new' version of the file.

Comment: How about setting `convert` flag to `true`? https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/update